# Natural sort of Unicode list by numbers before characters

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
scores2 = [u'4H', u'10H', u'18H', u'59H', u'84H', u'19A', u'38A', u'65A', u'88A', u'90A', u'']
```

Scores 2 prints out like this,
Can someone show me how to remove the unicode from the list and then sort by number value only so the last letter has no manipulation of the sort?. I have seen Natural Sort but im sure this only works with the letter before the number?

Comment: what is wrong with the unicode?

Comment: Have you actually tried `Natural Sort ` or is this only a speculation?

Comment: "Remove the Unicode"? That's like asking how to remove a number's base.

Comment: when I export it to a .txt file and then into excel the Unicode still remains so I need to remove it. Also I have tried the natural sort and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: why do you have two accounts?? http://stackoverflow.com/users/5149684/footystattowannab

Comment: "The Unicode still remains" - do you know what Unicode is?

Comment: Still wondering why the OP has 2 accounts....

Comment: needed answers quick and I got couldn't add new questions, so I have made a new account and abandoned the old one, thanks for your help before by the way

Comment: Question bans don't mean your account is broken and you need a new one; they mean your question quality needs work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scores2 = [u'4H', u'10H', u'18H', u'59H', u'84H', u'19A', u'38A', u'65A', u'88A', u'90A', u'']

print(sorted((x.encode("utf-8") for x in scores2 if x.strip()), key=lambda x:int(x[:-1])))
['4H', '10H', '18H', '19A', '38A', '59H', '65A', '84H', '88A', '90A']
```

Comment: I was about to comment you don't use re :p

Comment: @heinst, thought there may be more than one letter then saw in the question that  there is only one at the end

Comment: excellent that thanks ever so much

Comment: No worries,  you are just using the digits from the string to sort by slicing the letter off and calling int, `x.encode("utf-8")` just encodes the unicode string